# Unable to create plugin for Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin, magento2.1.0

I am trying to create a plugin for `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` class for `setPathInfo()`. However I am unable to do so. I am getting error

> [InvalidArgumentException] 
>       There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace

However I am able to create plugin for other classes.
There is no error in module, rest of the code is working fine.

My di.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http">
    <plugin name="testExample" type="\Vendor\PluginExample\Plugin\TestExample"/>
</type>
</config>
```

My plugin file -

```
namespace Vendor\PluginExample\Plugin;

class TestExample {

protected $logger;

public function __construct(
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
) {
    $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
}

public function afterSetPathInfo(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $pathInfo = null) {
    $this->logger->debug("works);

}
```

}

What am i doing wrong?? Can't we create a plugin for Framework classes ?

Comment: Definately, You can create a plugin for Framework class. have you check using remove var/generation folder?

Comment: To fix this error [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace, you can simply execute bin/magento command and the errors are displayed in bottom of the commands. Mostly, if you clear var/di, var/generation, var/cache & var/page_cache, this error will be gone.

Comment: @Rakesh , yes I have already tried to remove var/generation folder , but it didn't help. Can you confirm if the above code is correct ?

Comment: @Mike , I tried fixing the issue but it did'nt help

Comment: Appears this class can't have plugins, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11840

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your plugin-type class reference has an additional forward slash.

```
<plugin name="testExample" type="\Vendor\PluginExample\Plugin\TestExample"/>
```

I believe this one should be work. FYI: Didn't test the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http">
    <plugin name="testExample" type="Vendor\PluginExample\Plugin\TestExample"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

Clear the var/generation and try it out in Developer mode.

Additional info:

This `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` is the HTTP entry point in the `pub/index.php` `Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap` class. So it might be possible that we couldn't use this in a plugin but worth giving it a try.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-bootstrap.html

Cheers!